# Node.js Remote UDP server does not receive messages

Tags: node.js, udp

I have a basic problem with a UDP server in Node.js, I've used this little example:

```
// Remote server

var PORT = 3030;
var HOST = '127.0.0.1'

var dgram = require('dgram');
var server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

server.on('listening', function () {
    var address = server.address();
    console.log('UDP Server listening on ' + address.address + ":" + address.port);
});

server.on('message', function (message, remote) {
    console.log('Message received')
})

server.bind(PORT, HOST);
```

When I try to send a message from my computer, the server does not respond:

```
$ echo "test" | nc -u <server_ip> 3030
```

but, when I try to send the message from the server itself, the message arrives.

```
$ Message received
```

The server has static ip and I don't think it's a problem with the ports. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: What version of node are you trying this under?

Comment: The version is 0.10.25

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've work with the `unix` type for this kind of socket. It may work with `unix_dgram` as follow

```
var server = dgram.createSocket('unix_dgram');
```

Comment: Does not work, the code throws this: "throw new Error('unix_dgram sockets are not supported any more.');"

Answer (score 0):

Your server is only listening on localhost. You need to change your `HOST` variable to something else to be able to listen for messages from the outside world (e.g. `0.0.0.0` for all addresses, or a specific IP like `192.168.1.101`).

EDIT: I'm assuming that there is no router in between.

Comment: I've changed the `HOST` variable from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0, but server still does not respond.

Comment: Is there a firewall (e.g. iptables) on that machine blocking access?